# How to identify which table to delete a record when data coming from two tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables where some same kind of information kept. One table has approved information and other one contains pending(waiting for approval) data. I fetch data from both table and display in a same view. So user will see data from both the tables. User can delete those records. But when deleting I've a trouble with finding out which table I should delete.

Assume, table1(Approved info), table2(Pending info)

```
table1

id | name  | description | creator |
-----------------------------------
10 | test1 | N/A         | 100     |
11 | test2 | N/A         | 100     |
12 | test3 | N/A         | 101     |
13 | test4 | N/A         | 200     |


table2

id | name  | description | creator |
-----------------------------------
10 | test1 | N/A         | 105     |
11 | test2 | N/A         | 103     |
12 | test3 | N/A         | 106     |
13 | test4 | N/A         | 202     |
```

table1 has a record with id of 10; and table2 has a record with id of 10 in that table. Id is the primary key of both tables. Both record will show to user. Let's say user wants to delete the record related to id 12 came from table2. So I want to delete that record from table2. But how can I figure out which table to delete that record. Because I can't use id to figure out the table. I have tried using some kind of data attribute attached with
data coming from table2 to differentiate them. But anyone can change them by inspecting it. So what is the proper way for solve this issue?

Comment: You should put something in the HTML that indicates which table the row came from. You can use a hidden input for this.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah...I used a hidden input field. But the problem is anyone can inspect it and change that value and then submit. Isn't it a problem?

Comment: You can use data attributes too, if you are using javascript to fire ajax calls.

Comment: a proper DB table should include `status` column which has `pending/approved/rejected` etc. value.

Comment: Why would it be a problem? If they're not supposed to be able to delete the row from the other table, you need to add validation to prevent that.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. Got it. Because of they can delete from both table I don't need to care about they inspecting and sending changed values.

Comment: Your database is not well designed. Can your change it?

Comment: @JRichardsz Why do you say not well designed? Could you please explain it a bit?

Comment: Take a look a the @Bhaumik Pandhi comment. To have two tables with the same columns is not optimum and is the cause of your problems. Can you change your model?

Comment: @JRichardsz I just thought keeping a separate column is waste of space. Because in my case, after getting approved a record it's status field will always have approved status.

Comment: Do you think that to have 5 columns in one table (id | name  | description | creator | status) is a waste of space , versus 8 columns in two tables?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240323/discussion-between-kasun-and-jrichardsz).

Answer (score 0):

On any case, on any system, makes sense to have two to tables with same columns. That should be one of the firsts rules of database design. What's more, you discovered yourself how hard is to maintain a design like that. I see this on legacy systems developed with zero love to the code. In the future this will turn into a snowball. You should change it as soon as possible.

### status column

The status of and entity or resource, is classic requirement, usually implemented with one little column which called : status, flag, mode, etc. In your case, it could have these values (@BhaumikPandhi comment):

- pending/approved/rejected

```
id | name  | description | creator | status |
--------------------------------------------
10 | test1 | N/A         | 100     | pending|
```

If you are worried to the database optimization, you could use a [tinyint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html) with these equivalence in your documentation:

- 1 = pending
- 2 = approved
- 3 = rejected

### status table

You could keep your first table called **record**

```
id | name  | description | creator |
```

And create another one called **record_status** with 2 columns, in which record_id is a FK of **record** table

```
record_id | status |
```

Anyway, the status column is the most easy a classic approach to your requirement.